# Advanced linear gradient animation CSS like android swipetorefreshlayout

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I want this effect
http://antonioleiva.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/SwipeRefreshLayout.gif

At the moment I have this one http://codepen.io/anon/pen/czulD

Can someone code it like native android swipetorefresh layout?

See code below (same as CodePen example)
HTML

```
<html>
  <body>
  <div class="preloader"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.preloader {
     height: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}
.preloader {


    background-size: 100px 100px;
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, #fecf23 25%, transparent 25%,transparent 50%, #fecf23 50%, #fecf23 75%,transparent 75%, transparent);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(135deg, #fecf23 25%, transparent 25%,transparent 50%, #fecf23 50%, #fecf23 75%,transparent 75%, transparent);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #fecf23 25%, transparent 25%,transparent 50%, #fecf23 50%, #fecf23 75%,transparent 75%, transparent);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(135deg, #fecf23 25%, transparent 25%,transparent 50%, #fecf23 50%, #fecf23 75%,transparent 75%, transparent);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(135deg, #fecf23 25%, transparent 25%,transparent 50%, #fecf23 50%, #fecf23 75%,transparent 75%, transparent);
background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #fecf23 25%, transparent 25%,transparent 50%, #fecf23 50%, #fecf23 75%,transparent 75%, transparent);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fecf23', endColorstr='#34c2e3',GradientType=1 );
  background-color: #34c2e3;


    -ms-animation: animate-stripes 1.2s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: animate-stripes 1.2s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: animate-stripes 1.2s linear infinite;
    animation: animate-stripes 1.2s linear infinite;
   -webkit-animation: animate-stripes 1.2s linear infinite;

    transition: width .4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: width .4s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: width .4s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: width .4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: width .4s ease-in-out;
}

@-ms-keyframes animate-stripes {
    0% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }

    100% {
        background-position: 200px 0;
    }
}

@-o-keyframes animate-stripes {
    0% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }

    100% {
        background-position: 200px 0;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes animate-stripes {
    0% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }

    100% {
        background-position: 200px 0;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate-stripes {
    0% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }

    100% {
        background-position: 200px 0;
    }
}

@keyframes animate-stripes {
    0% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }

    100% {
        background-position: 200px 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since linear-gradients are, in fact, rendered images, they are not animatable (yet).

You can get the effect thinking about it in that way.

The way I use to animate gradients is to interpolate opacity between multiple elements with different gradients. Like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/L9p4swzx/

```
    .container{
        position:relative;
        width:300px;
        height:300px;
        border:1px solid black;
    }
    .container h1{
        display:block;
        position:relative;
        z-index:2;
    }

    .animated {
        z-index:1;
        position:absolute;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%, #ff670f), color-stop(21%, #ff670f), color-stop(56%, #ffffff), color-stop(88%, #0eea57));
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ff670f 0%, #ff670f 21%, #ffffff 56%, #0eea57 88%);
        background: linear-gradient(135deg, #ff670f 0%, #ff670f 21%, #ffffff 56%, #0eea57 88%);
        animation:gra1 5s infinite;
        animation-direction:alternate;
        -webkit-animation:gra1 5s infinite;
        -webkit-animation-direction:alternate;


        animation-timing-function:linear;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
    }
    .animated2 {
        content: ' ';
        z-index:1;
        position:absolute;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;

        border:1px solid black;
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%, #ff670f), color-stop(10%, #ff670f), color-stop(40%, #ffffff), color-stop(60%, #0eea57));
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ff670f 0%, #ff670f 10%, #ffffff 40%, #0eea57 60%);
        background: linear-gradient(135deg, #ff670f 0%, #ff670f 10%, #ffffff 40%, #0eea57 60%);
        animation-direction:alternate;
        -webkit-animation:gra2 5s infinite;
        -webkit-animation-direction:alternate;

            animation-timing-function:linear;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
    }
    .animated3 {
        content: ' ';
        z-index:1;
        position:absolute;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;

        border:1px solid black;
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%, #ff670f), color-stop(5%, #ff670f), color-stop(10%, #ffffff), color-stop(40%, #0eea57));
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ff670f 0%, #ff670f 5%, #ffffff 10%, #0eea57 40%);
        background: linear-gradient(135deg, #ff670f 0%, #ff670f 5%, #ffffff 10%, #0eea57 40%);

        animation-direction:alternate;
        -webkit-animation:gra3 5s infinite;
        -webkit-animation-direction:alternate;

            animation-timing-function:linear;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes gra {
        33% {
            opacity: 1;
        }
        80% {
            opacity: 0;
        }
        100% {
            opacity:0;
        }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes gra2 {
        33% {
            opacity: 0;
        }
        66% {
            opacity: 1;
        }
        100% {
            opacity:0;
        }
    }

@-webkit-keyframes gra3 {
    33% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    66% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
```

With a little bit more of tweaking you can get decent animation.

But for your case, there's a better solution, which is animate the background position, since the gradient changes are similar.

http://jsfiddle.net/3L6tybd5/1/

```
.container{
    position:relative;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.container h1{
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}

.animated {
    z-index:1;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%, #ff670f), color-stop(5%, #ff670f), color-stop(20%, #ffffff), color-stop(44%, #0eea57));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ff670f 0%, #ff670f 5%, #ffffff 20%, #0eea57 44%);
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #ff670f 0%, #ff670f 5%, #ffffff 20%, #0eea57 44%);
    background-size:200%;
    background-position:0px 0px;
    animation:gra1 5s infinite;
    animation-direction:alternate;
    -webkit-animation:gra1 5s infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction:alternate;

    animation-timing-function:linear;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;

}

@-webkit-keyframes gra1 {
    33% {
            background-position:0px 0px;
    }
    66% {
        background-position:-50px -50px;
    }
    100% {
        background-position:-150px -150px;
    }
}
```

Notice that I changed some values of the animation and the gradient so it renderer bigger than the container.

Hope it helps

Comment: It helps but in the end product I choose another animation now :) Anyways thanks for your help ;)